# Filtering two concatenated values

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of users that I want to filter by their `full_name` and `address`. And I'm having trouble filtering their names using angular filter because their names are stored in `first_name` and `last_name` seperately.

Here's what I've done so far:

**TS**

```
userSearch = {
    full_name: "",
    address: "",
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="userSearch.full_name" placeholder="Name" />
<input [(ngModel)]="userSearch.address" placeholder="Address" />

<tr *ngFor="let user of usersJson| filter:userSearch">
    <td>{{user.first_name+' '+user.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you create the filter pipe?

Comment: No i didn't create one

Answer (score 0):

you must create your custom pipe

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filterUsers"
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(users: any, full_name: string, address: string): any {
    if (full_name || address) {
      return users.filter(user => {
        const user_full_name = `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`;
        
        // This will return true if user_full_name is equal full_name
        // or if user.address is equal address
        // **Note** if you want them both to be true then change || to &&
        return (
          user_full_name.toLocaleLowerCase() ===
            full_name?.toLocaleLowerCase() ||
          user.address.toLocaleLowerCase() === address?.toLocaleLowerCase()
        );
      });
    }
    return users;
  }
}
```

Import filter Pipe in your module

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, FilterPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Use the pipe in your Components Html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="full_name" name="full_name"  placeholder="Name"/>
<input [(ngModel)]="address" name="address" placeholder="Address"/>

<tr *ngFor="let user of users | filterUsers: full_name : address">
    <td>{{user.first_name+' '+user.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.address}} </td>
</tr>
```

In your component ts file, you can add two variable

```
 full_name: string;
 address: string;
```

and also created a [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oyzxvv?file=src/app/filter.pipe.ts)